# How do I update an initialized variable used in Python Class?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with a list. I am trying to return the list in a different class, but it returns the list as the original empty list instead of the new list with elements (SOLVED!!).

```
class Whatever:
    def __init__(self,thing):
        self.list=[]
        self.thing=thing

    def list_append(self):
        df1=pd.read_csv('job.py')
        df2=pd.read_csv('home.py')
        self.list.append([df1,df2])
        return self.list
    def new_function(self):
        return self.list

function=Whatever('thing1')
function_output=function.new_function()
print(function_output)
```

Comment: This code never calls `list_append()`, so of course `self.list` is still in its original empty state.

Comment: I am trying to send the results of the list_append() function to the new_function(). I dont exactly know how to do this.

Comment: @NickBosio You need to call a function for it to run to get results from it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I am trying to send the results of the list_append() function to the new_function()", because looking at the code, I can see that `list_append()` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code:

1. First, you should write `def __init__(self, thing1):` instead of `def __init__:`
2. You have to call the method `list_append()` to fill your `list`.

Here is the working code:

```
class Whatever:
    def __init__(self, thing1):
        self.list=[]
        self.thing=thing1

    def list_append(self):
        df1=pd.read_csv('job.py')
        df2=pd.read_csv('home.py')

        self.list.append([df1,df2])
        return self.list

    def new_function(self):
        self.list_append() # to call the above method
        return self.list

function=Whatever(thing1)
function_output=function.new_function()
print(function_output)
```

> **Test**: Let assume `df1 = "hello"`, `df2 = "world"` and `thing1 = "good"`. The above code will produce the result `[['hello', 'world']]`.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but what if I want to loop through self.list. For some reason, my loop output still gives me a list instead of a dataframe. I am going to re-edit my code to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling it in a different class but in a different method, but this may be just a terminology error, so nothing serious. But the most important error will probably be this:

You are trying to call output of the list_append function, but you never call it, so you have to do in the new function something like this:

```py
def function(foo):
    return(foo)

def new_function(foo_foo):
    function(foo)
```

Comment: Lol. Ignore the __init__(self) portion. I thought the return self.output of a method can be used throughout the code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I tried to help but then I realized I am writing nonsense, my apologies, I deleted the rubbish part